# Complexity of assembly built-in?

Tags: discussion

Consider a challenge:

> Given a positive integer \$n\$, compute \$n^2\$. The solution with the least asymptotic time complexity in terms of \$n\$ wins. [fastest-algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-algorithm)

<sub>(let's temporarily ignore that it's too boring or too trivial)</sub>

- Is it clear enough?
- Assume it's clear enough. Consider this C++ answer. On normal machines, `int` is the same type as `int32_t`, which can only hold integers in range \$\left[-2^{31}\dots2^{31}-1\right]\$)

  > `int f(int n){return n*n;}`

  Is it a valid answer?

  - If it is, it will likely be compiled to a single assembly instruction.

    > `imul edi, edi`

    What should be its asymptotic time complexity?
  - If it isn't, why?

---

Note: Challenges can be objectively and unambiguously defined when there is a set of "base" operations that the program can use, for example:

> Given a list \$A\$ of positive integers, sort the list \$A\$. You are not allowed to access the list directly, however you can do the following operations by calling black-box procedures:
>
> - Compare two numbers at index \$i\$ and \$j\$ (call `compare(i, j)`). Returns `signum(A[i] - A[j])`.
> - Swap two numbers at index \$i\$ and \$j\$ (call `swap(i, j)`)
>
> The solution with the asymptotically least number of calls to `compare` function wins.

<sub>(yes, this is also trivial, with a provably optimal \$O(n \log n)\$ solution)</sub>

However, in that case they will be [fewest-operations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fewest-operations), not [fastest-algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-algorithm).

---

> Note: PeterTaylor's answer at revision 1's "moreover..." part was pointing out a flaw in the question. Now I've fixed it, as I think that it's better to fix it rather than ask a new question.

Comment: The complexity of `imul edi, edi` is 1.  It's a constant time operation.  If you really want it to be interesting, you have to make the integers big.

Comment: I'd close the challenge as unclear unless they specified the range of integers (or indicate that all integers need to be handled), even with [tag:fastest-algorithm].  But that's the thing, if you bound `N`, any `O(N)` algorithm becomes `O(1)`.

Answer (score 2):

> - Is it clear enough?

No, so the rest of the question is moot. To be clear enough, the example question should explain in sufficient detail what types are admissible. For integers, this is actually quite tricky: some languages have built-in big integers; some languages *only* have big integers; for others the natural type to use would be an array of some integer type, but then you need to consider whether the base is allowed to be different to the size of the type (taking into account that not all languages have unsigned types, and not all languages have *signed* types) and whether or not it's acceptable to mix endianness; and for others the natural type is a unary string.

Moreover, in many challenges (possibly not this one) the difference between unary representations vs higher bases is very important in strict comparison of asymptotic complexity, which is expressed in terms of the *length* of the input rather than the *represented value* of the input. Thus, for example, "*Input a positive integer and print the integers from 0 up to and including the input value*" is trivially implemented in quadratic time for unary representations, but the length of the output is superpolynomial in the length of the input if the input is given in base 2 or higher.

Comment: I don't see how the edit invalidates part of the answer, but the edit does introduce a major error into the question. [tag:atomic-code-golf] is about the number of "symbols" in the source code, not about the number of function calls made in execution.

Comment: As far as I can see, none of the existing challenges that work with integers specify how to represent integers in memory, such as [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/143016/approximate-floating-point-number-with-n-digit-precision) or [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/166773/find-elements-in-an-array-computing-a-given-function-value). Are those clearer than the example question, and if so, why?